# pass the value of vTicketQty and vTicketPrice to calcTotal

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var vTicketType;
vTicketType = prompt(" What type of Tickets is required?");
document.write("The Ticket Type is: " + vTicketType);

var vTicketQty;
var vTicketQty = parseInt(vTicketQty);
vTicketQty = prompt("How many Tickets are required?");
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("The Ticket Qty is: " + vTicketQty);
document.write("<br/>");

 if (vTicketQty < 0) {
  document.write("Invalid Qty"); 
  document.write("<br/>");
}

function calcPrice(vTicketPrice) {
var vTicketPrice; 
if (vTicketType.toLowerCase() == "a") {
  document.write("Ticket cost is:$100");
  vTicketPrice = 100;
} else if (vTicketType.toLowerCase() == "b") {
  document.write("Ticket cost is:$75");
  vTicketPrice = 75;
} else if (vTicketType.toLowerCase() == "c") {
  document.write("Ticket cost is:$50");
  vTicketPrice = 50;
} else {
  document.write("-1");
  vTicketPrice = -1;
 }
}

function calcTotal(vTotalPayment) {
var vTotalPayment;
if (vTotalPayment > 0) {
  document.write("<br/>" + "Total payment required is: $" + vTotalPayment);
} else {
  document.write("<br/>" + "Invalid data supplied");
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
<title> Ticket Calculator </title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Student Name: Evangelos Cocotsi ID: 101615609</h1>
 <h1>Ticket Calculator</h1>
 <script src="W4P.js"> </script>
 <script>calcPrice()</script>
 <script>calcTotal()</script>
</body
</html>
```

i need to pass the value of vTicketQty and vTicketPrice to calcTotal. i have tried adding things but none of it seems to work. every time i run the code i get "Invalid data supplied" how do i fix this?

Comment: here calcPrice() and calcTotal() called before variable assigned

Comment: I've tried putting calcPrce() and calcTotal() before my variables but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Why don't you use HTML form controls? It's better then using `document.write`

Comment: i mean to say in the code both functions are called before variable assigned which will not give you desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Need to modify the variable declaration and function call. If function called before variable (with assigning value) will not give the desired result.

```
calcPrice() and calcTotal() and variables-  vTicketQty and vTicketPrice.
```

check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xffhzv3b/)